# How to stop my scroll function once MySql has fetched all the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

This script is working fine. But, how to stop my scroll function and the scroll loader .gif (to hidden) once MySql has fetched all the data.

Or, if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks for the help!

Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var limit = 20;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_city_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"ps_load_data.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("No Data Found");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#imgLoader').html('<img class="animated-gif" src="img/ajax-loader.gif">');
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }

 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  load_city_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_city_data(limit, start);
   }, 3000);
  }
 }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't anything involved with the 3rd party scripts and CSS (Google API script, CDN CSS and CDN script) which I thought initially.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I downloaded them all and run them locally. (Only Google API was involved, nothing to do with any CDN script)

This code is running fine. Stops the scroll and also hides the ajax-loader.gif now.

**What is figured out was the problem in my url:"ps_load_data.php"**

Actually I was trying to run two sql queries, and hence it wasn't hiding my gif image. When, I put the script in different file, it was working fine.

It took a lot of time and effort to understand that it was conflicting with my earlier script. Since, it didn't gave me any error, it took so long. Thanks!