# How to load and stop Ajax based vertical scroll function + gif image loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have not been able to fully achieve this. The problem is this function works once and then stops. Am I missing a loop here?

I have tried to move the `else { }` block everywhere, but it doesn't help. I have also tried to put the condition `else if (data=='')` but that also didn't helped.

If I move this function

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive') {
```

outside of `if(data !=='')` then **my scroll function and the gif image doesn't stops** even after the last raw been fetched from the database.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<script>
var limit = 20;
var start = 0;
var action = 'inactive';
var timeOutId;

function load_city_data(limit, start) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"ps_load_data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{limit:limit, start:start},
        cache:false,
        success:function(data) {
            $('#load_data').append(data);
            if(data !== '') {
                $('#imgLoader').html('<img class="animated-gif" src="img/ajax-loader.gif">');
                action = "inactive";
                $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive') {
                    action = 'active';
                    start = start + limit;
                    timeOutId = setTimeout(function(){
                        load_city_data(limit, start);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            else {
                $('#load_data_message').html('<div class="reached">You have reached at the end of the listings</div>');
                action = 'active'; 
                $(window).off('scroll');
                clearTimeout(timeOutId);
                $('img[src="img/ajax-loader.gif"]').remove();
            }
            });
            } 
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(action == 'inactive') {
        action = 'active';
        load_city_data(limit, start);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is mentioned here: [How to stop my scroll function once MySql has fetched all the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660881/how-to-stop-my-scroll-function-once-mysql-has-fetched-all-the-data)

**Also, this is the working script**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var limit = 100;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_country_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"ps_load_data.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("No Data Found");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<img src='img/ajax-loader.gif'>");
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }
 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  load_country_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_country_data(limit, start);
   }, 2000);
  }
 });
});
```

**Just make sure your url:"ps_load_data.php" has only one fetching query running**, otherwise it will conflict and might not hide/stop your gif image even after last row of data has been fetched. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `exit();` immediately after while loop ending. It can work even if you're running multiple queries in your **ps_load_data.php**.